# How to interact with other terminals?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal

I have 2 terminal windows, T1 and T2. T1 runs a monitor application and has to run full time.

T2 (a bash script) is used to control T1 and to tell T1 to start a scan.
My problem is that I want to write a script which starts a scan, but i need to know when the scan is done in order to continue the script in T2 properly.

When starting the scan the only feedback is in T1, when the scan is done T1 says "Succuess...", in T2 there is no feedback.

Is there a way to write a script to read out the success message of T1?

Cheers

Comment: I'd say this has nothing to do with the terminals themselves, but instead you need some way to communicate with the monitoring program, like pipes or sockets.

Comment: How does T2 tell T1 to start a scan exactly?

Comment: @MarkSetchell T2 starts a python script. The result is displayed in T1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few ideas spring to mind...

- If the python script starts the scan, presumably it knows when the scan is finished and if it worked - i.e. its exit status. If that is the case, you could either modify the python script to write the exit status of the scan to a file called `exitstatus.txt` and monitor that file from T2, or put a wrapper around the python script which does the same thing. Note that for this to work properly, you would want to delete the `exitstatus.txt` file before starting each scan.
- Another idea might be to pipe the output of the scan command into `tee` and from there to a file and read that file from T2.
- Another idea might be that you run the command `tty` in T2 before scanning to get the terminal's device special filename - something like `/dev/ttys001`. Pass that to T1 as a parameter to your python script and it can then write on terminal T2 with a command like:

  `echo Success > /dev/ttys001`

Answer (score 0):

You can use named pipes for IPC.  Try this in one terminal:

```
mkfifo /tmp/fifo && read LINE < /tmp/fifo && echo $LINE; unlink /tmp/fifo
```

and in the other terminal:

```
echo foo > /tmp/fifo
```

Communication in both directions is probably easier using sockets and netcat.